# Update from java 1.7 to latest version

Tags: java, jdk

How can i update to the latest version of `java` if i have already installed on my pc `java 1.7`.

If i should remove it first, how can i do that?

Comment: I'm guessing the down vote is because you did not say what you tried or what did not work, for future reference. You tried something before posting the question, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look for an actual repository here
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/webupd8_java

Answer (score 0):

You could have also done `sudo apt-get pruge openjdk-*` then `sudo apt-get install default-jre`.

Just an idea if you need to fix packages or whatever in the future!